# how to save EF (STE) entities in to temporary tables

Tags: entity-framework, temp-tables

is there a way, how to save EF (STE) entities in to temporary tables?

I'm trying to achieve this:

1) save my STE to temporary tables
2) run some stored procedures on them
3) depending on result from procedures, do something else..

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF will not handle this. EF saves the entity to table(s) defined in mapping but the mapping is defined at design time. You cannot decide to save the entity to other table at runtime through EF without changing its mapping and that would be highly inefficient - changing mapping at runtime is not a supported use case so it is quite complicated and moreover applying a new mapping is the most expensive operation in EF.

You need just another stored procedure to insert your data to temporary table. Depending on the logic you expect you can either map that procedure to insert operation for the entity (but in such case your procedure will be used every time you insert a new entity) or simply execute it directly.

Comment: Thank you Ladislav. I will take a look on mapping procedure to insert operation.